# The difference between the reputation shown in the "all" tab, and the "year" tab is not 101 for all the users who get the association bonus

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

My reputation shown on https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all is different from the reputation shown on https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I thought the difference could be the association bonus, but also the first shown user has the association bonus, and the difference between the reputation shown in those pages is not 101, as I would expect.

> [image: StoneyB]

> [image: kiamlaluno]

Comment: +1: Confirm, there's a constant error by rep 1 point for all users around me. I believe the difference may be caused by *earned* rep versus *total*, but it does not happen on the other SE sites.

Comment: The difference should be 101 for every user who got the association bonus, but it is not so. Why that happens is a mistery, to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed: Now the difference is 1 for everybody.

[image: "all" tab]

[image: "year" tab]